# MFMailComposeViewController not responding or populating

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is a Swift 2.0 project. I have a MFMailComposeViewController that appears as expected, but does not populate the contents, and does not respond to user interaction, except for the Cancel button, which dismisses it.

The send button is greyed out. None of the text fields respond to user touch.

Running on an iPhone 6+ iOS 8.4.1, Xcode 7.0b6

What am I missing?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@IBAction func hitSendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
    let emailTitle = "Title goes here"
    let emailBody = "Blah blah blah blah."
    let recipientAddress = "EMAILGOESHERE"

    mailViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    guard let mailvc = mailViewController else {
        return
    }
    mailvc.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailvc.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mailvc.setMessageBody(emailBody, isHTML: false)
    mailvc.setToRecipients([recipientAddress])
    self.presentViewController(mailvc, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    }
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    if let vc = controller.presentingViewController {
        vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            self.mailViewController = nil
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Apparently it's a bug in Xcode 7.0b6.

I recompiled the app under Xcode 6.4 (after changing the 'guard' statement to an 'if let') and it runs without problem.